# iOS Methods get the call but does not change color of UIVIew

Tags: ios

I am trying to change the color of UIView to indicate network connection. In my methods `turnIndicatorViewOff` and `turnIndicatorViewOn`, I am changing the color of `indicatorView` to red and green respectively. And It's not showing the color change. Those methods get the call. I tried showing an alert and it works fine too but I can't hide or change the color of `indicatorView`. Also it's not nil. What could be wrong?

My code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    indicatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, VIEW_WIDTH, 2)];
    indicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:indicatorView];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pubNubConnectionNotification:) name:@"MQTT_CONNECTION_NOTIFICATION" object:nil];
}

- (void) pubNubConnectionNotification: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    if([[notification object] boolValue])
    {
        [self turnIndicatorViewOn];
    }
    else
    {
        [self turnIndicatorViewOff];
    }
}

- (void) turnIndicatorViewOff
{
    indicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void) turnIndicatorViewOn
{
    indicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Comment: Ensure the notification comes back on main thread?

Comment: Yeah Notification was not coming on the main thread. It worked after using perform selector. Thank you :)